# Db design relational design vs serialized string

Tags: database, serialization, database-design, relational-database

I am making a website for a smartphone reparation store. There is a table with smartphones. And a table with reparations, because reparations are the same throughout all the phones, but the prices for every reparation are different for every phone.

I want to know the pros and cons of two these two methods.
1: a relational table with:
- smartphone id
- reparation id
- reparation price

2: a field in the smartphone table containing the reparation id and prices in serialized or json form, example:
Screen replacement has id 2 and costs 50,- for iphone 4, and home button replacement with id 5 and costs 20,50- for iphone 4.

There would be a field in the smartphone table that is text and contains "{"2":"50.00","5""20.50"}"

Comment: What are your own thoughts? Why do you think one might be better than the other?

Comment: I think method 2 is more compact, I cant think of any cons. Maybe the more experienced can..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relational design gives you more options to search the data using native SQL.  Using the serialized string would be easier to code on the front end, but you would have difficulty trying to search, order, and filter through thousands of records with SQL when using WHERE clauses on a serialized string.

I would go for the relational model, because shortcuts lead to headaches down the road.